# Load protected method after button click

Tags: java, android

Call the protected method only when the button is clicked for changing the app language configuration. Since I am new to android and java i could not figure a way out. Thanks in advance.

```
    @Overide
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_language);
    btnAss = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonAss);
    btnEng = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonEng);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectLanguage);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnAss.isChecked()) {


               //here it should call the protected method attachBaseContext
               // attachBaseContext(getApplicationContext());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });


}
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase,"as"));
}
```

The ContextWrapper is as follows

```
 public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextThemeWrapper {

public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base,R.style.AppTheme);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale sysLocale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
    if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
    return new MyContextWrapper(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.setLocale(locale);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to add the call to the method.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnAss.isChecked()) {

           //here it should call the protected method attachBaseContext
           attachBaseContext(getApplicationContext());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

But, I think that what you want to do is to change that once the app is running, is that rigth?

Comment: yes, but by default when the activity loads the attachBaseContext methods gets called but it has to be only after the button is clicked.